# Импорт xml в базу mysql на c# winforms

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, winforms

С чего начинать такой импорт на c# помогите?!
Может какие ссылки есть?
Или возможно кто-то реально может помочь с написанием (подробнее в профиле)?
Компьютер с Visual Studio уже есть ))
Новичокс

Comment: Книгу по C# уже прочитали?

Comment: Книга есть, то в ней такого нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Чтение XML:*

1. Убедитесь в том, что проект содержит ссылку на сборку System.Xml.dll
2. Укажите директиву using в пространстве имен System.Xml, чтобы
   избавиться от необходимости указывать объявления XmlTextReader далее
   в коде. Директиву using необходимо использовать перед всеми
   остальными объявлениями.

   using System.Xml;
3. Создайте экземпляр объекта XmlTextReader и укажите путь к вашему xml
   файлу:

   `XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("path/to/your/file.xml");`

либо:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
```

4. Далее можно читать документ как показано ниже:

Например у вас xml следующего вида:

```
<DataChunk>
    <ResponseChunk>
        <errors>
            <error code=\"0\">
                Сообщение о ошибке
            </error>
        </errors>
    </ResponseChunk>
</DataChunk>
```

Что бы прочитать сообщение о ошибке потребуется такой код:

```
XmlNodeList errorNodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/DataChunk/ResponseChunk/Errors/error");

foreach(XmlNode errorNode in errorNodes)
{
  // чтение ошибки
  string errorCode = errorNode.Attributes["code"].Value;
  string errorMessage = errorNode.InnerText;
}
```

Так же можно описать структуру вашего xml документа и просто дессериализовать.

Пример описания структуры:

```
[XmlRoot("StepList")]
public class StepList
{
    [XmlElement("Step")]
    public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
}

public class Step
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Desc")]
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

xml к нашему описанию:

```
string testData = @"<StepList>
                        <Step>
                        <Name>Name1</Name>
                        <Desc>Desc1</Desc>
                        </Step>
                        <Step>
                        <Name>Name2</Name>
                        <Desc>Desc2</Desc>
                        </Step>
                    </StepList>";
```

Дессериализация:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StepList));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(testData))
{
    StepList result = (StepList) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Подробнее о чтении XML можно узнать [тут](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/307548) и [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx)

Далее, когда вы прочитали данные, нужно обеспечить связь с базой данной.

*Подключение к базе данных:*

1. Так как вас в качестве данных выступает mysql, вам потребуется MySQL
   Connector. Скачать можно [тут](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
2. Используя NuGet установить [Entity Framework](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/)
3. Используя NuGet установить [MySql.Data.Entities](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data)
4. Добавить в апп конфиг в секцию `connectionStrings` строку подключения к базе данных:  `<add name="MyDB" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=localhost; port=3306; Initial Catalog=mydb; uid=myuser; pwd=mypass;" />`

В секции `entityFramework`(которая должна автоматически появится после установки EF) добавить в секцию `providers` MySQL провайдер:

```
<providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
</providers>
```

Создать контекст:

```
using MyApp.Core.Entities.Directory;
using MyApp.Data.Mapping;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyApp.Data
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext() : this("MyDB") { }
        public MyContext(string connStringName) : base(connStringName) {}
        static MyContext ()
        {
            DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration());
        }

        public DbSet<Country> YourTable { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(EntityMap<>).Assembly);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Подробнее как работать с Entity Framework можно почитать [тут](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19233/Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm)

Comment: Нда... Неплохо.

Comment: @Андрей а вы ожидали, что вы все сделаете в пару строк кода? :D

Comment: @Андрей ну если вы готовы предложить адекватную компенсацию за трудозатраты, то почему нет :) skype: mstislav.pavlov